# unable to hide a link which contain certain text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following markup , which have a groups of links, and i want to hide all the links that have the word "question" ,  such as "answered questions":-

[image]

so  wrote the following script:-

```
<script>
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.ms-pivotControl-surfacedOpt a:contains("question")').hide();
  });
</script>
```

but did not hide anything ,, can anyone adivce on this please ?

Comment: It would be good, if you add your HTML mark up as a code.

Comment: If  you type this in console, what is shown: `$('.ms-pivotControl-surfacedOpt a:contains("question")')`

Comment: i don't see `question` but i see `questions`

Comment: @Shehary but questions contain question is this correct ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The jQuery's selector must be:

```
$('a.ms-pivotControl-surfacedOpt:contains("question")').hide();
```

Comment: OWO your code worked well,, but what are the differences between your code and mine can you advice please?

Comment: jQuery selector works like that: find a tag, then with ms-pivotControl-surfacedOpt css class and then that contains "question" text.

Comment: In your question, jQuery find all nodes in the page with css class ms-pivotControl-surfacedOpt, and then find inside links that contains question text.

Comment: The difference between Javier's and your code @johnG is the fact that your code looks for all the elements with class `ms-pivotControl-surfacedOpt` that contain an `a` element - if you don't understand why, brush up on your [CSS selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Comment: @johnG the css selectors are friends! ;)